# Need to display data attribute result in multiple time using id, is there any alternate way is there to achieve this result?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to display the input element multiple times using the data-view-id but it displaying only once. Can anyone help me how to display the same value in multiple times.how can i use class instead of id here

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("input")
    .keyup(function() {
      var value = $(this).val(),
        dataViewId = $(this).data("view-id"); // get your data-attribute value
      // use this value as a selector:
      $(dataViewId).text(value);
    })
    .keyup();

  $("select").change(function() {
    var value1 = $(this).val(),
      dataViewId1 = $(this).data("view-id1"); // get your data-attribute value
    // use this value as a selector:
    $(dataViewId1).text(value1);
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control saninput" id="name" data-view-id="#namen" placeholder="Type your answer here...">

<span id="namen"></span><br/>
<span id="namen"></span><br/>
<span id="namen"></span>
```

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements with the same id property. Okay, you can but you may not. Because only the first element is addressed. Never use multiple elements with same id. It is treated as HTML error.

Comment: is there any alternate way is there to achieve this result. how can i use class instead of id?

Comment: You can check here:
https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/